# Remove odd elements from ArrayList while iterating

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of Strings and I'm trying to remove the odd elements of the ArrayList, i.e. list.remove(1), list.remove(3), list.remove(5) etc.

This is the code I'm attempting to use which throws up an IllegalStateException error:

```
int i = 0;
    for (Iterator<String> it = words.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0 && it.hasNext())
        {
            it.remove();
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Is there a better (working) way to do this?

Comment: Seems fine. You want more performance than this?

Comment: Stack trace and message?

Comment: Just call it.next() before the IF condition inside the FOR loop as given in the answer below.

Comment: What @Sudhanshu said. If you check the [docs for `remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) you'll see that calling `next()` first is a must: _Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
    for (Iterator<String> it = words.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
    {
        it.next(); // Add this line in your code
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            it.remove();
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me! Why do I need to add the it.next() line though?

Comment: hashNext() just checks if there is any element available after the current element. Initially iterator will be at -1th position. In your case you are trying to remove an element at the -1th position(which is not possible).Thats why you are getting IllegalStateException.it.next() moves the iterator to the nextposition. Hope it made it clear

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this to remove every second element starting from `words[1]`. No need to check whether the index is odd, when we remove an element we can just increment `i` and that will be the next odd number.

```
int i = 1;

while (i < words.size()) {
    words.remove(i++);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone this Array or copy that odd element into another array. During iterate time it was used same object so if you remove its index and state was changes.

```
int i = 0;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String word:words)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {

            //it.remove();
            list.add(word);
        }

        i++;
    }
    words.removeAll(list);
```

now just remove this all by passing this list to your words list object

```
words.removeAll(list);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this behave the way we want it to if some elements were to appear more than once? I have the feeling it might remove elements that we shouldn't - I don't have a computer nearby to try.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an iterator, because you don't need to examine the elements. Just use [`List.remove(index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29):

```
for (int i = words.size() - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        words.remove(i);
    {
}
```

Note that you must count down, not up with this approach because removing an element shuffles e everything after to the left

If your list is immutable (explains the exception) make a copy first:

```
words = new ArrayList(words);
```

Comment: There is no delete(int index) method on list. Instead there's a remove(int index)

Comment: But if you remove an element from the list, it will affect on the further elements which are not processed yet. They will change their index number and there's a risk to get ArrayOutOfBoundsException, because you are iterating over list with old (bigger) size. But actual list size will be smaller.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov if you read my answer you'll see it caters for all your objections. Please read it again.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this.

```
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.remove(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below also works fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3,
                4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            list.remove(i);
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

yielding

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: This will do exactly the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: @R.J changing the initial value of i will sort it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use next() and then call remove() ---

```
    int counter = 0;
    for (final Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        iterator.next();
        if (++counter % 2 != 0) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Integer> removeImpairElements(List<Integer> integers){
int j = 0; 
for(int i = 0 ; i < integers.size(); i++){
  if( i % 2 == 0){
    integers.set(j, integers.get(i));
    j++;
  }
}
int half = integers.size()%2==0 ? integers.size()/2 : integers.size()/2 + 1;  
integers.subList(half , integers.size()).clear();
return integers;
```

}